# write the command to send a message to one or more receivers in a java client server chat application

Tags: java, server, client, chat

I've tried to write a java client server application for chatting between clients privately.  I am searching for a way to write the command to send a message to one or more receivers, I thought of handling it with a command like:

**/send UserName UserName msg**

but I pretty soon discovered that the character in between usernames and the message couldn't be repeated in the message because then it wouldn't know what is the message and what are the recipients, using a prearranged character also seemed to have some implications, like the inability to use that character in usernames or the message.

What would be a good way to handle such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can determinate what is message and what are usersNames by splitting on last and first occurrence of delimiter in your case empty string. Lets say user input is *inputStr*

```
int firstOccurance = inputStr.indexOf(" ");
int lastOccueance = inputStr.lastIndexOf(" ");
```

And split it like this

```
String command = inputStr.substring(0,firstOccurance); // /send
String users = inputStr.substring(firstOccurance+1,lastOccurance); //UserName UserName
String msg = inputStr.substring(lastOccurance+1); //msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Using space as delimiter will lead to a issue that message itself cannot include a space.

Instead you can use special delimiter to indicate a particular substring is a message.

Some very common delimiters are `| ;`